# how get anchor tag url hash values in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get this url anchor tag hash values? i am trying this code but this shows undefined.

HTML & Jquery 3.2:

```js
$(function(){
    // get current url hash values.
    var current = window.location.hash;
 
    $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        alert($this.hash);       
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php#aboutus">About Us</a>
      </li>
    <ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question.
For example, for `About us`, you want to get `index.php#aboutus`, `#aboutus` or just `aboutus`?

Comment: yes i want to get #aboutus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.hash` isn't a property of a [jquery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), but rather is a property of an [HTMLAnchorElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) (a class which extends from the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) class), thus you're getting `undefined`.

So, instead of creating a jQuery object using `$(this)`, you can reference the actual element by just using `this`:

```js
$(function() {
  // get current url hash values.
  var current = window.location.hash;

  $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li a').each(function() {
    alert(this.hash);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.php#aboutus">About Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: actually, you can use `this` directly without creating a jquery object

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need jquery, `hash` is a vanilla Js prop on anchors 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_hash.asp

```js
$(function() {
  // get current url hash values.
  var current = window.location.hash;

  $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li a').each(function() {
    alert(this.hash);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.php#aboutus">About Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the elements and than check for `href` includes `#` or not. if includes split it with `#` and get the value using `pop`

```js
function getMeHash(){
  let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#navbarSupportedContent ul li a')
  let hashes = []
   anchors.forEach(e=>{
    if(e.href.includes('#')){
      hashes.push(e.href.split('#').pop())
    }
   })
   console.log(hashes)
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php#aboutus">About Us</a>
      </li>
    <ul>
</div>

<button onclick='getMeHash()'>Get me hash </button>
```